# How to remove column one by one from a dataframe through a loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe with 200 columns and I want to start removing column from reverse order like last column one by one through a loop till 5 or 10 columns remain in a dataframe and store in newdataframe like e.g two features (column, Result)

```
column    results 
-----------------
200         94%
199         93%
.
.
150         98%
```

By removing column one by one, I want to find the accuracy of a machine learning model for each column when its removed.

How to write this code in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `iloc` attribute for this

Here's an example with 3 columns

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'col1': range(3),
  'col2': range(3),
  'col3': range(3)
})
for i in range(len(df.columns) - 1, 0, -1):
  print(df.iloc[:, :i])
  print()
```

Output

```
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     1
2     2     2

   col1
0     0
1     1
2     2
```

Comment: how i can do this through a loop and it the end i have just to store the result in one dataframe not on multiples because i have 200 coloumns and when i start from reverse order then i will stop on 10 or 20 Value

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhan Does the updated post using loop answer your question?

Comment: yeah thats great its working but can i stop on some specific criteria like after reaming coloumn to be 5-10 then stop

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhan It's just a loop. You can stop whenever.